# Swift 3 - AdMob not showing on existing View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to integrate AdMob into my Swift-based app but it doesn't work no-matter what code I try.

I created a new View Controller and used the **exact** same code as my 'Home' controller and that seems to work, but it will not work on any of the existing ViewControllers that I have.

My current storyboard looks like this:
[image: Current storyboard]

and my current Ad code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
import AudioToolbox

class AdTest: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    // Ad banner
    var adMobBannerView = GADBannerView()
    let ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-9999999999"




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Init AdMob banner
        initAdMobBanner()
    }





    // MARK: -  ADMOB BANNER
    func initAdMobBanner() {

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            // iPhone
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
        } else  {
            // iPad
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 468, height: 60)
        }

        adMobBannerView.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID
        adMobBannerView.rootViewController = self
        adMobBannerView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)

        let request = GADRequest()
        adMobBannerView.load(request)
    }


    // Hide the banner
    func hideBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
        UIView.beginAnimations("hideBanner", context: nil)
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        banner.isHidden = true
    }

    // Show the banner
    func showBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
        UIView.beginAnimations("showBanner", context: nil)
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        banner.isHidden = false
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

My AdTest ViewController shows this:

[image: AdTest ViewController]

Whereas my Home ViewController doesnt show ads at all:

[image: Home ViewController]

Comment: You should not display the real value of `ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID` :)

Comment: Try to implement `func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
  print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}` and check if there is an error...

Comment: ^ that returns 'Request Error: No ad to show.' - But no ads show even if i use the test ID on the google website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue, turns out that AdMob will not work if you change the global user defaults.

As a temporary fix, i've added this right before the ad is shown.

```
//MARK : - Load table data
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "AB-" + UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString])
////////////
//GET CODE//
////////////

//MARK : - Load AdMob
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone;         CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15A372"])
initAdMobBanner()

//Set browser back so the app works
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "AB-" + UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString])
```